# Electromagnet experiment

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics

I was reading about an experiment on cyberphysics.co.uk.

You set up a circuit as follows:

[image]

Then:

1. The current through the circuit is varied while the number of turns of wire around the iron nail core is kept constant. It is found that the electromagnet can hold more paperclips (made into a paperclip chain) as you increase the current through the circuit.
2. The current is held constant while the turns of wire are increased in turn -- it is found that the electromagnet can hold more paperclips as you increase the turns.

This shows that the strength of the magnetic field around the electromagnet is proportional to both the current through the circuit and the turns of wire.

Now I have two questions:

1. Is there an equation that shows this relationship explicitly?
2. What is "strength of the magnet" in this equation? Is there a symbol for this?

Finally, how do we know that we have captured all the variables that can go in such an equation? For example, if we wanted to find the area of a circle, then because a circle only depends on its radius, and once the radius is determined the circle is fully described, then we immediately know that the area of a circle only depends on its radius, i.e. $A_{circle}=f(radius)$ for some function $f$. Indeed, $A_{circle}=\pi(radius)^2$.

On the other hand, how do we make this analysis for an experiment like the one above? I understand that we have to create a model to avoid overcomplicating things with too many variables, but how do we know when to stop?

Thanks

Comment: Everything is here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/solenoid.html or in any EM textbook.